# Is there a name for this pattern?

Tags: number-theory

I'm not a mathematician, but I was calculating multiplication of some numbers and I saw a pattern emerging. What is this phenomenon called? And does it happen in other cases?

```
    6 *     9 =         54
   66 *    99 =       6534
  666 *   999 =     665334
 6666 *  9999 =   66653334
66666 * 99999 = 6666533334

6,6    * 9,9    = 65,34
6,66   * 9,99   = 66,5334
6,666  * 9,999  = 66,653334
6,6666 * 9,9999 = 66,66533334
```

Any ideas? Looks like 6's and 3's are introduced.

Comment: $99999A= 100000A -A$.  (This fact is behind one of the trivial demonstrations of "vedic" "math".)

Comment: Ehm... can you translate it to layman's terms?

Comment: E.g., if $A=5$, then you have $$99999\times 5 = 100000\times 5 - 5 = 500000 - 5 = 499995.$$  If $A = 66666$ you have $$99999\times 66666 = 100000\times 66666 - 66666 = 6666600000-66666=6666533334.$$  But it works for all $A$, and it is the distributive law of multiplication together with the fact that $99999=100000-1$.

Answer (score 3):

You are multiplying $2/3 \times (10 - 10^{-k})$ by $10 - 10^{-k}$, and so you obtain
$2/3 \times (10 - 2 \times 10^{1-k} + 10^{-2k})$.  The initial $6$'s come from 
$2/3 \times 10 = 6.666\ldots$.  The $5$ and $3$'s come from subtracting 
$4/3 \times 10^{1-k} = 13.333\ldots \times 10^{-k}$.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know if it has a name, but here’s a way to see what is happening.

$$\begin{align}
65,34 +0,66&=66 & & = 6,6\times(9,9+0,1)=6,6\times10\\
66,534 +0,066&=66,6 & & = 6,66\times(9,99+0,01)=6,66\times10\\
66,6534 +0,0066&=66,66 & & =6,666\times(9,999+0,001)=6,666\times10\\
66,66534 +0,00066&=66,666 & & =6,6666\times(9,9999+0,0001))=6,6666\times10
\end{align}$$

Similar patterns would occur with repeated digits other than $6$, but the repeated $9$s are more special.

Comment: Yeah... 3 and 6 introduce 2's and 7's in a similar way.

Comment: And 9 and 3 introduce 3's and 6's as well...

Comment: Thanks, Jonas. Since the question was asked with commas, I tried to answer with commas, but didn’t quite do it right. I’ve edited the answer to make all the decimal points commas, following the OPs home convention.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is you are multiplying by something close to 10.  9; 9.9; 9.99; 9.999 ... converges to 10 so you are just observing convergence. and 0.666666666666666

it is much better to see it as

0.6 * 0.9 = 6 * 0.1 * (1-0.1)

and

0.66 * 0.99  = 6 * (0.1 + 0.01) * (1 - 0.01)

and

0.666   * 0.999   = 6 * (0.1+0.01+0.001) * (1- 0.001 )

etc.

basically the product of two brackets converges to 1/9  *  1 so you are observing something converging to 6/9. more and more digits are becoming exact.